# Is it possible to change the color of the scrollbars in gVim / Vim in windows os

Tags: text-editor, vim

As the title says, was it possible for gVim editor to have customize scrollbars in windows OS? If it wasn't natively supported are there workaround to achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have to modify the GUI widget styling directly in the source code and build your own version of the Vim executable, or use a Windows tool (if such exists; I remember something called *Window Blinds* that allowed custom styling) that can tweak the appearance of arbitrary Windows applications.

<sup>The latest source code and runtime files can be downloaded via FTP or retrieved from Mercurial; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details.</sup>